# Where to find Debian security update release dates

Tags: debian

While digging into my Debian system, I could not find any way to tell how long security updates had been pending. Even on the [Debian package page](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/openssl) and [security-tracker](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/source-package/openssl) sites, no dates are mentioned (except the dates specific CVE's were released).

Even the `apc-cache show` command doesn't seem to have any date information, only version info:

```
Package: openssl
Version: 1.0.1k-3+deb8u2
Installed-Size: 1102
Maintainer: Debian OpenSSL Team <pkg-openssl-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15), libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.1)
Suggests: ca-certificates
Description-en: Secure Sockets Layer toolkit ...
Description-md5: 9b6de2bb6e1d9016aeb0f00bcf6617bd
Section: utils
Priority: optional
Filename: pool/updates/main/o/openssl/openssl_1.0.1k-3+deb8u2_amd64.deb
Size: 677058
MD5sum: 4fdbbe730aa2c2d994f78fc48b85c6fa
SHA1: d1efa6d94f617b259ddac00fbeec7af2c7ab7405
SHA256: 66588530fb24beeb96508bfb950e4b9893d433174dcd9e55c88b7233c1eb0893
```

Ideally I'd like to take the output of a command like:

```
sudo apt-get -s dist-upgrade | grep "^Inst" | grep -i securi
```

clean it up a bit and then use some automated source of information to retrieve the dates. Unfortunately it doesn't look like the `.deb`'s have this information.

Is the release date information available anywhere?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @NeilSmithline, yes, where is the release date found?

Comment: I'd search the [Debian security announcement mailing list](https://lists.debian.org/debian-security-announce/). You are probably interested in [this search](https://lists.debian.org/cgi-bin/search?P=openssl&DEFAULTOP=or&B=Gdebian-security-announce&SORT=&HITSPERPAGE=10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for OpenSSL security update release log in particular. If that's the case, you can check the [changelog for OpenSSL package in Debian](https://launchpad.net/debian/+source/openssl/+changelog) on [launchpad.net](https://launchpad.net).

You can also look at the diffs in the [queue for proposed updates](https://release.debian.org/proposed-updates/stable.html) on [release.debian.org](http://release.debian.org).

Even better, you could look at the [Debian changelog server (?)](http://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs) for changelogs. To look for OpenSSL changelogs, visit

> https://packages.debian.org/changelog:openssl
>   
> or
>   http://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs/main/o/openssl/

Comment: Nice! While not quite as awesome as it would have been if it were available from `apt-cache`, that definitely has the dates I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: You can try something like `wget -O- -q http://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs/main/o/openssl/openssl_1.0.1k-3+deb8u2_changelog | sed /--/q` which will download the changelog for `openssl 1.0.1k-3+deb8u2` and print the very first section of the changelog file to the terminal. You can make the command look prettier and query the version of the package instead of hard-coding it.

Comment: For the other URL that redirects to the latest changelog, use this: `curl -s -k -L "https://packages.debian.org/changelog:openssl" | sed /--/q`